# Java UserInputs from User to Contain no Strings

Tags: java, arraylist, user-input

I'm making a program of battleship with the user going against the computers random inputs choices in an 8x8 grid. 
What I'm having trouble with is that I don't want my program to crash if my user inputs a String, such as "asdfklasdn", "h", etc... It doesn't crash if its an integer, such as 1,5,etc. Is there any way to change this without changing the rows and columns to strings?  If I use try catch, it just gives me an error in the if-else statements right after in the userFire method.
Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Battleship
{
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
public static final boolean DEBUG = false;

public static void breakln()
{
    System.out.println("─────────────");
}

public static void createBoard(String [][]board)
{
    for( int r = 0; r<board.length; r++)
    {
        for(int c= 0; c<board[0].length; c++)
        {
            board[r][c] = "-";
        }
    }
}

public static void showBoard(String[][] board)
{
    breakln();
    for(int r =0; r<board.length;r++)
    {
        if(DEBUG == true)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c<board[0].length;c++)
            {
                System.out.print(" " +board[r][c]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        else
        {
            for(int c = 0; c<board[0].length;c++)
            {
                if(board[r][c].equals("S"))
                {
                    System.out.print(" " + "-");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(" " + board[r][c]);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
    breakln();
}

public static void createShip(String[][] board, int size)
{
    if(Math.random()<0.5)
    {
        int col = (int)(Math.random()*5);
        int row = (int)(Math.random()*7);
        for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
        {
            board[row][col+i]="S";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int col = (int)(Math.random()*7);
        int row = (int)(Math.random()*5);
        for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
        {
            board[row+i][col]="S";
        }
    }
}

public static int userFire(String[][] board, int hits, int torps)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int row,col;
    System.out.println("You have: " + torps + " torpedos");
    System.out.println("Select row to fire in: ");
    row = input.nextInt(); 
    while(row>8||row<1)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid. Enter a valid row (1-8)");
        row = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Select column to fire in: ");
    col = input.nextInt();
    while(col>8 || col<1) 
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid. Enter a valid column (1-8)");
        col = input.nextInt();
    }

    if(board[row-1][col-1].equals("S"))
    {
        hits++;
        System.out.println("HIT ");
        board[row-1][col-1] = "×";
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("MISS");
        board[row-1][col-1] = "Ø";
    }
    return hits;
}

public static void endOfGame(int hits, int torps)
{
    if(hits<4)
        System.out.println(" LOSE ");
    if(torps<1)
        System.out.println("You have lost all your torpedos.");
    else
        if(hits>=4)
        {
            System.out.println("WINNER");
        }
    System.out.println("");
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(" BATTLESHIP ");
    System.out.println("");

    String[][] board = new String[8][8];
    createBoard(board);
    createShip(board,4);
    int torps = 25;
    int hits = 0;

    while(torps>0 && hits<4)
    {
        showBoard(board);
        hits = userFire(board,hits,torps);
        torps--;
    }
    endOfGame(hits, torps);
}
```

}

---

I've tried everyone's answers, but I received errors in this code.

```
if(board[row-1][col-1].equals("S"))
    {
        hits++;
        System.out.println("╠══ HIT ══╣");
        board[row-1][col-1] = "×";
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("╠══ MISS ══╣");
        board[row-1][col-1] = "Ø";
    }
    return hits;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add try/catch block inside row=input.nextInt() or every variable who receives input;

Here's sample code

```
 try{
     row = input.nextInt(); 
}
catch(Exception)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just catch the exception, e.g.

```
try {
  row = input.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
  System.err.println("Input is not an integer"); // or do some error handling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
    System.out.println("Invalid. Enter a valid row (1-8)");
    String userInput = input.next();
    try {
        row = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
    } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
        // Failed : Invalid input. Take actions if required. 
        // May be prompt user for correct input
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use while(input.hasNextInt()) and println a message saying you only want ints?

Or a catch block as BroSlow said.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  xxx = input.nextInt();
} catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
   doXXXLoop();
}

// ....

public void doXXXLoop() {
  System.out.println("Not a valid number. Enter another:");

  try {
    xxx = input.nextInt();
  } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
    doXXXLoop();
  }
}
```

***Unlike other code, this will easy repeat until a valid int is entered. Replace XXX with Row or Col or whatever you want.***